# Aportuguesamento de nomes próprios da mitologia grega

Tags: ortografia, acentuação

Encontro o nome do titã *[Κοίος](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ceos_(mitologia))* escrito como Céos e Ceos. Qual é a forma correta e, de maneira mais geral, quais são as regras para o aportuguesamento de nomes próprios da mitologia grega no Brasil e em Portugal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**: Creio que ambos estão corretos.

A forma correta, especialmente para nomes de uso habitual, é aquela consagrada pelo uso.

Tanto "Céos" quando "Ceos" são encontrados com frequência, e variações como, por exemplo, "Ceo" (e.g., [aqui](http://www.educ.fc.ul.pt/docentes/opombo/hfe/protagoras2/links/titas.htm)) também são usadas.

Dado que nomes da antiguidade grega são referências culturais que antecedem o próprio português, e que sempre o acompanharam, suas formas atuais resultam da evolução histórica da língua, em que regras para o aportuguesamento (ver abaixo) são apenas um dos fatores.

Essa posição é defendida, por exemplo, no [artigo de 1955](https://doi.org/10.11606/issn.2316-9141.v11i23p177-185) de Antenor Nascentes, na Revista de História da USP ([e-print](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/268314696.pdf)), em resposta a [outro artigo](https://doi.org/10.11606/issn.2316-9141.v8i17p211-218) na mesma revista, por José Lazzarini Júnior, criticando o segundo tomo de seu *Dicionário Etimológico da Língua Portuguêsa*. Destaco:

> A etimologia postula a forma *Ifigenia* (com acento na silaba *ni*, como recomendava Julio Ribeiro), mas o uso, dissimilando, criou a forma *Efigênia*, com *e* inicial e com a terminação talvez influenciada por *Eugênia*.
> A quem devemos obedecer? À etimologia ou ao uso? Entre uma forma etimologica morta e uma forma usual viva não trepido um só instante. Prefiro a forma viva, com todos os seus erros etimologicos.

**Normas Gerais**

A descrição mais extensa que encontro on-line das regras para o aportuguesamento (transcrição/romanização) foi a da página [Wikipédia:Romanização/Grego](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikip%C3%A9dia:Romaniza%C3%A7%C3%A3o/Grego), que inclui várias tabelas de correspondência e que, com relação a diacríticos, estipula:

> o acento agudo [...] faz parte do sistema ELOT 743, e, por sua equivalência com o diacrítico presente no português, deve ser preservado em toda transliteração e transcrição na Wikipédia

Essa tendência à manutenção do acento agudo (e de outros) na transliteração do grego é evidente em outras fontes (por exemplo [aqui](http://www.ufrgs.br/nele/12.-idiomas/grego-classico/exemplos-de-textos) ou [aqui](https://revista.classica.org.br/classica/article/view/123)) e seria um argumento a favor da forma "Céos".

Mas aqui é importante frisar que essa norma se refere à [*transliteração*](https://dicionario.priberam.org/transliterar), que não coincide necessariamente com a *transcrição*/aportuguesamento (vide o [Ciberdúvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/onomagulo-uma-transcricao-do-grego/32834)). Por exemplo, o nome da ilha de Σαντορίνη seria transliterado como "Santoríni", mas também [se pode grafar](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/o-toponimo-grego-santorini-grecia/34895) o topônimo sem o acento agudo e essa é inclusive a forma mais comum em português. Outro exemplo nesse sentido é o filósofo Σωκράτης, que é transliterado "Sōkrátēs" e transcrito "Sócrates".

Como exemplo de aplicação das regras de aportuguesamento da página da Wikipedia mencionada acima, podemos voltar ao titã Κοίος e considerar como seria sua tradução: " Κ " corresponde ao "C" e o ditongo " οί " a "é", mas o " ος " corresponderia, por estar após vogal, ao "u", nos dando "Céu" como tradução, ou, se tomarmos o ditongo por uma consoante, "o", resultando em "Céo".

Resta portanto explicar porque a forma "Céos" se tornou a mais adotada. Uma possibilidade talvez seja uma influência do francês que, em seu verbete sobre o titã, lista quatro possíveis grafias, todas terminadas em "os": *Céos, Cœos, Coéos, Koios*.

Comment: Sobre "Céos" e "Ceos", numa rápida busca ambos me parecem comuns, talvez se possa dizer que ambos estão corretos? Nesse caso talvez um argumento etimológico (ou outro) seja um critério válido de desempate. :)

Comment: é uma boa resposta para situações em que há uma ou outra forma claramente consagrada pelo uso.

Comment: @toliveira Concordo, a resposta estava limitada a apenas esse caso, então a reformulei substancialmente, e agora acredito que ela está mais geral.

Comment: grato pela gentil reformulação!